# android notification icon displayed weird

Tags: android, notifications

[image]
[image]

my code is as below. notification is shown first pic. and when I drag down to open notification bar, and show like second one.  I wonder why there is a nicely displayed big icon and right bottom side, there is white blank icon...

How can I correct it? code is as below.

```
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notify);

final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

builder.setAutoCancel(false);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
builder.setOngoing(true);
```

Comment: please use png image whose background should be transparent

Comment: its just use png image with white and transparent cuts

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("Your Content Text")
                .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

  private int getNotificationIcon() {
        boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
        return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.app_icon_trans : R.drawable.app_icon;
   }
```

And make sure your image background should be transparent.Version lollipop and above required transparent background image for notification.

Answer (score 1):

The image you are using for notification is not valid/not supported by android. 
What I think your issue is that the notification icon could be multi coloured. 
Ideally the icon should be single coloured. The android status bar displays icon in only two shades, white + color. You can find more info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar)